# How to set up the correct display of data in the admin panel

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I'm need to set up the correct display of data in the admin panel of integer values from the database as floating point values.

I am trying to use decimal, integer, number from official documentation, but I haven’t found the option of “division” type in any of these types.

```
/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper): void
{
    $listMapper
        ->add('int properties which need to display in float view (like 00.00)', 'decimal', [
            'division' => 100
        ])
    ;
}
```

It is necessary that the value that is stored in dB as an integer number be displayed in the admin as a float:

```
(int from db / 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's inbuilt method `number_format()`.The `number_format()` function formats a number with grouped thousands.
Syntax:

```
number_format(number,decimals,decimalpoint,separator)
```

Example:

```
<?php

echo number_format(2, 2);
?>
```

Result:

```
2.00
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer). `number_format()` also rounds, but I do not need rounding and I do not fully understand how i can implement this function in `protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper): void;`

Answer (score 0):

I usually use sprintf for this kind of problem.

```php
sprintf('%.2f', 100);
```

output :

```
string(4) "100.00"
```

The format string `%.2f` means : Display a float `f` with two digit after the dot `.2`

Here's the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) of this function if you want more details.

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably forgot to specify it in the question I asked. But the problem is that when i save the value in db, it is multiplied by 100, and then it comes to the admin in the form `(necessary for displaying float * 100)`, i need to do a reverse translation)

Comment: I see, what don't you just divide the value in in the sprintf?

Comment: I figured it out, set up an entity getter to output float instead of int. Thanks for answers)